# Trouble with single digit value in getting the value from a URL variable

Tags: jquery, selector

I have a dynamic page that I am using the following code to grab & display the appropriate heading to a div that is associated with the clicked link. The code works fine with double digit values for the variable but not any of the 1-9 values.

```
//cat is the value (1-43) being passed into a function containing the following line:
$("#menuContainer a[href$="+cat+"]").parent().parent().parent().find("H3").text();
```

The href is in an dynamically created LI which has an associated h3 header. I want to display the header text in another div. I've tried using "a[href*="+cat+"]") as well and that fails for values from 1-9. Should I filter this in a different way?

Comment: share how your url look like

Comment: Could you please post the relevant HTML markup and the variable `cat` value.

Comment: the url has a variable like... subCatID=2 where that value could be a number from 1-43. So I'm just trying to find the href where the "cat" equals a number from 1-43. This is a filtering question. The code works for values 10-43 but not in finding a single h3 for 1-9 since those numbers appear in double digit numbers. ie 12, 41 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `$` from `href$` and try like this

```
$("#menuContainer a[href=" + cat + "]").parent().parent().parent().find("H3").text();
```

[demo jsfiddle with href$](http://jsfiddle.net/qAWr7/) 
in this fiddle when you click on "Click here - 3", it should alert 3 but it will alert 31323. Because href$ if finding and concatenating 3, 13 and 23

[demo jsfiddle with href](http://jsfiddle.net/qAWr7/1/) in this link it works as expected and alert 3

Comment: Thanks but that returns nothing. I should have mentioned that I also tried href=, href~=, href*= and href$=. The results for values in the 1-9 range return multiple headers probably because a value like "2" returns mulitple h3 tags because of the links that have a value of 20-29 & 12.

Comment: Its working fine with `href=` I have created demo jsfiddle and added links in above answer

Comment: I updated my code to use a href$="+"="+cat+"]" and got the results I want.